# Eliminate $t$ from $h=\frac{3t^2-4t+1}{t^2+1}, k=\frac{4-2t}{t^2+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections

> Eliminate the parameter $t$ from $$h=\frac{3t^2-4t+1}{t^2+1}$$ $$k=\frac{4-2t}{t^2+1}$$

This is not the actual question. The question I encountered was:

> Perpendicular is drawn from a fixed point $(3, 4)$ to a variable line which cuts positive x-axis at one unit distance from origin. Circle $S(x, y) = 0$ represents the locus of the foot of perpendicular drawn from point $(3, 4)$ to the variable line. If radius of $S(x, y) = 0$ is $\sqrt{λ_1}$ and length of tangent drawn to $S(x, y) = 0$ from origin is $\sqrt{λ_2}$ , then determine $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

**My attempt:**

I attempted the original question by assuming the variable line as $x+ty-1=0$ and calculating the coordinates of foot of perpendicular $(h,k)$ on it from $(3,4)$. I got the coordinates $(h,k)$ as $$(h,k)\equiv \left(\frac{3t^2-4t+1}{t^2+1}, \frac{4-2t}{t^2+1}\right)$$

I am clueless after this point on how to eliminate $t$. Solving for $t$ from either of the equations and substituting it in the other is very cubersome and not a very efficient method because I'm preparing for a competitive exam. I verified using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eliminate+t+from+x%3D%283t%5E2-4t%2B1%29%2F%28t%5E2%2B1%29%2C+y%3D%284-2t%29%2F%28t%5E2%2B1%29&wal=header) that the locus is a circle but am unable to obtain it in the standard form.

I am looking for a relatively short method/trick for these type of locus. Thanks.

Comment: $h-2k=\frac{3t^2-7}{t^2+1}=3-\frac{10}{t^2+1}=-7+\frac{10t^2}{t^2+1}$, so consider $-\frac{10}{h-2k-3}-1=t^2=(\frac{10}{h-2k+7}-1)^{-1}$.

Comment: In M2 using grobner bases `R=QQ[s,t,x,y,z,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 2]`
`I=ideal(x-(3*t^2-4*s*t+s^2),y-(4*s^2-2*s*t),z-(t^2+s^2))`
`gens gb I --  matrix {{x^2+y^2-4*x*z-4*y*z+3*z^2, t*x-s*y+4*s*z-3*t*z, s*x+t*y-s*z, 10*t^2-x+2*y-7*z, 10*s*t+2*x+y-6*z, 10*s^2+x-2*y-3*z}}`

$x^2+y^2-4x-4y+3=0$ or $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=5.$

Comment: "*I verified using WolframAlpha...*" $\;-\;$ You can ask WA for the actual [equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28+%28t%5E2%2B1%29h+-+%283t%5E2-4t%2B1%29%2C+%28t%5E2%2B1%29k-%284-2t%29%2C+t+%29).

Comment: @RiverX15 Lookup polynomial [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Case_of_two_equations_in_two_unknowns).

Comment: The title is "Eliminate $t$ from $h=\frac{3t^2-4t+1}{t^2+1}, k=\frac{4-2t}{t^2+1}$", but you wrote "This is not the actual question" and "I am looking for a relatively short method/trick for these type of locus". This looks misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$h-3=\frac{-4t-2}{t^2+1}\implies\frac{h-3}k=\frac{-4t-2}{4-2t}=\frac{2t+1}{t-2}=2+\frac5{t-2}$$
$$t=\frac5{(h-3)/k-2}+2=\frac{2h+k-6}{h-2k-3}$$
Then substitute this into the second equation to get an implicit form:
$$k=\frac{4-2(2h+k-6)/(h-2k-3)}{(2h+k-6)^2/(h-2k-3)^2+1}=\frac{-10k(h-2k-3)}{(2h+k-6)^2+(h-2k-3)^2}$$
$$(2h+k-6)^2+(h-2k-3)^2=-10(h-2k-3)$$
$$5h^2+5k^2-30h+45=-10h+20k+30$$
$$h^2+k^2-4h-4k+3=0$$
$$(h-2)^2+(k-2)^2=5$$
From this we get $\lambda_1=5$ and $\lambda_2=3$.

Answer (score 5):

The circle $S(x,y)=0$ passes through $A(3,0),B(1,4)$ and $C(3,4)$. (why?)

Since $\angle{ACB}=90^\circ$, the center $D$ of the circle is the midpoint of the line segment $AB$.

Let $E$ be the tangent point. Then, note that $\triangle{ODE}$ is a right triangle where $DE$ is the radius.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you actually want to eliminate $t$ and form an equation of $h$ and $k$ if it is that then I hope it is a shortcut.
$$h+tk=1$$
$$\implies \frac{1-h}{k}=t$$
Now, $\require{cancel}$
\begin{align}&k=\frac{4-2\frac{1-h}{k}}{\frac{(1-h)^2}{k^2}+1}\
\implies& k=\frac{\frac{4k-2+2h}{k}}{\frac{h^2+1-2h+k^2}{k^2}}\
\implies &k=\frac{4k-2+2h}{\cancel{k}}\frac{k^{\cancel{2}}}{h^2+1-2h+k^2}\
\end{aliɡn}\
h²+k²-4h-4k+3=0

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I have no computer i have to type in mobile so it is too hard to type so I send the image  -José Carlos Santos

Comment: @MdjavedAkhtar The first step is a clever observation (though the end result is wrong). Unfortunately, it's going to get overlooked unless you post it in a friendlier MathJax format.

Comment: @dxiv do you want to say that I cannot cancel out K from both sides then ok K =0 will be another solution if it is not then pls again comment

Comment: @MdjavedAkhtar in the first step : $h+tk=1$ it should be $t=\frac{1-h}{k}$ not $t=\frac{h-1}{k}$.

Comment: Indeed, @islamm is correct.  $h+ tk= 1 \implies t =\frac {1-h}k$, provided $k\neq 0$.  Else (of k=0), then  h= 1.  Please correct your subsequent work.

Comment: Will not then it be - t =( 1-h )/k

Comment: @MdjavedAkhtar no !, $kt=1-h$.

Answer (score 1):

For the quick method:

By Thales’s theorem, we immediately have that the locus is the circle with $(3,4)$ and $(1,0)$ on a diameter. Thus, it has centre $(2,2)$ and radius $\sqrt 5$.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other good answers, we can use the substitution $t=\tan\frac12\theta$. Then
$$h=3-\frac{4\tan\tfrac12\theta+2}{\sec^2\tfrac12\theta}\quad\text{and}\quad k=\frac{4-2\tan\tfrac12\theta}{\sec^2\tfrac12\theta}$$or
$\,h=2-\cos\theta-2\sin\theta\,$ and $\,k=2+2\cos\theta-\sin\theta.\,$ Hence
$$5\cos\theta=2k-h-2\quad\text{and}\quad5\sin\theta=6-2h-k,$$
giving $(2k-h-2)^2+(6-2h-k)^2=25$. This reduces to the circle
$$(h-2)^2+(k-2)^2=5,$$
which has centre $(2,2)$ and radius $\surd5$.